# Como verificar se um controle é filho de outro? "Control.IsChildOf"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho 3 painéis:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ParentPanel" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="AnnoyingPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="P" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Como posso verificar se `P` é descendente de `ParentPanel`?

Comment: Cara você está traduzindo as QA do SO? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892999/how-to-check-if-a-control-is-child-of-another-control-control-ischildof)

Comment: @RodrigoReis _Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow, desde que elas beneficiem a sua comunidade. Tenha sempre em mente, porém, que traduções automatizadas ou mal escritas não são permitidas._ http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/q/1/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um *[extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)* recursivo como este:

```
public static bool IsChildOf(this Control c, Control parent)
{
    return ((c.Parent != null && c.Parent == parent)
            || (c.Parent != null ? c.Parent.IsChildOf(parent) : false));
}
```

O que resulta em:

```
P.IsChildOf(ParentPanel); // true
ParentPanel.IsChildOf(P); // false
```